# Visually differentiate Sitecore clones

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

Is there a way to visually distinguish sitecore clones? I'm looking for a way so that anytime a clone gets created, the cloned items are in a different color.

Comment: Bear in mind that clones become normal items when published.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through the magic of a data provider, you can control the appearance of clones.  Here is an example class:

```
using Sitecore.Data.DataProviders;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.StringExtensions;

namespace Example
{
    public class CloneStyleDataProvider : DataProvider
    {
        public string Style { get; set; }

        public override Sitecore.Data.FieldList GetItemFields(Sitecore.Data.ItemDefinition itemDefinition, Sitecore.Data.VersionUri versionUri, CallContext context)
        {
            var fields = context.CurrentResult as FieldList;
            if (fields == null || fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Source].IsNullOrEmpty() || !fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Style].IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                return null;
            }
            var newFields = new FieldList();
            newFields.Add(Sitecore.FieldIDs.Style, Style);
            return newFields;
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the following patch in a .config file

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore> 
       <dataProviders>
            <cloneStyle type="Example.CloneStyleDataProvider,Example" patch:before="methodGroups">
                <Style>color:#333399;</Style>
            </cloneStyle>
        </dataProviders>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You can then specify CSS styles that get put into the item's appearance/style field.

Comment: Also found out that sitecore 6.5 rev 120706 already does this :)

Answer (score 4):

You can enable the "Cloned Items" gutter icon, which will mark clones with an icon to their left in the Content Editor.  You can activate this feature by right-clicking on the left side of the content tree, as shown below.  The icon is a clickable link to the base item.

Also note that clones appear in gray text in the content tree.

---

[image: Clone gutter icon]

Comment: These gutter icons are notorious for cross-browser issues, though these may have been cleaned up.